# Link my own HTML homepage to Wordpress product pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm making a website for an artist. He wants a custom homepage with links to WordPress pages for each of his performances. My idea is that these 'product' pages — the pages with the information about his work — can be made using WordPress, so that he can easily add and edit them later. But I would like to make the homepage myself, using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Is there an easy way to replace the homepage of a WordPress site with a fully custom page?

Comment: Yes, have fun: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, You should design a webpage, Save it as .php file and convert it to wordpress standard page by adding this code to beginning of file

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: FrontPage
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage My Theme
* @since My Theme 1.0
*/
?>
```

Then in wordpress admin page add a new page(for example title as **FrontPage**) and assign created custom file as template for this page.
After all in admin section, **Setting** > **Reading** activate **A static page (select below)**  and select page you've added (**FrontPage**) as **Home Page**